# Custom events tracking in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log custom events with Firebase Analytics within my React app and I've followed examples but nothing is appearing in my events feed/dashboard.

Can anyone see any issues with this?

Trying to work out whether it's my code or Firebase.

````
import firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  databaseURL: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX",
  measurementId: "XXX"
});
firebase.analytics();
firebase.analytics().logEvent("view_search_results", { search_term: "example" });```
````

Comment: It may take some time before the events show up in the Firebase console. You can use this [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) Chrome extension in the meantime to see if the events are being sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you Frank, that's really useful. What would a successful sending look like in the console? Does 'Processing GTAG command' mean its successfully sending, as that's where my console stops reporting?

Comment: I know I used this extension once, but can't recall how for the life of me. This might be useful though: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging